# At a time how many rows we can update using Documentum update DQL query?

Tags: documentum6.5

While updating more rows i.e  1,00,000 rows at a time in Documentum table , That time i am getting below error.

Error :

**[DM_SESSION_E_NON_EXIST_OBJ]error:  "The object identified by SET_PUSH_OBJECT_STATUS does not exist."; ERRORCODE: 100; NEXT: null**

At a time how many rows we can update using Documentum update DQL query ?

Answer (score 1):

Your error is caused by [incorrect implementation in DFC](https://blog.documentum.pro/2014/11/21/maximum-length-of-dql-statement/), which limits the maximum length of DQL queries to ~63800 bytes

Comment: Thanks Mr. Andrey ,  As per query limit (63800 bytes) i have made portioned of the query . Now my query is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK the underlying database will set the limits. If you run the query in DA or eg. FME dqMan you are able to see the generated SQL that are run.
If you run into problems it might be due to inconsistencies in the repository- in that case you might want to run the Consistency Checker job to ensure your repo is in good shape before doing large updates.